# cut out the shape goes out of the body

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put the diamond shape in the right-top corner of the page, not the full diamond shape. Some portion of diamond I want to cut out. How can I cut out the portion that goes outside the body part or how can we make those portion transparent?
What I am trying to achieve:

[image]

```css
.diamond2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: -208px 447px;
  FONT-SIZE: 13PX;
  FONT-WEIGHT: 600;
}

.diamond2:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  content: '';
  height: calc(100% - 0px);
  width: calc(100% - 0px);
  border-radius: 10%;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
  border: 11px solid #ff5a05;
}
```

```html
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="margin-top: 100px;">
  <div class="container" align="center" style="margin-top: -52px;background-color:#000000;width:1120">
    <table width="1120" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>
            <h1 style="font-family:helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;padding-left: 15px;padding-top: 10px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1><br>
            <p style="font-family:helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;padding-left: 20px;font-size: 16px !important">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,.</p>
          </div>
          <div class='diamond2' id="diamond2">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <hr style="border: 1px solid #ff5a05;width: 1085px;">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have added the .container class in css file and set its **position: relative** and **overflow: hidden**. Since the .container class is parent to the .diamond2 class so when we set the position of .container class to relative and overflow: hidden its child div's become absolute to it and Afterwards the cut out portion of the diamond wont be visible.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.diamond2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: -208px 447px;
  FONT-SIZE: 13PX;
  FONT-WEIGHT: 600;
}

.diamond2:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  content: '';
  height: calc(100% - 0px);
  width: calc(100% - 0px);
  border-radius: 10%;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
  border: 11px solid #ff5a05;
}
```

```html
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="margin-top: 100px;">
  <div class="container" align="center" style="margin-top: -52px;background-color:#000000;width:1120">
    <table width="1120" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>
            <h1 style="font-family:helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;padding-left: 15px;padding-top: 10px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1><br>
            <p style="font-family:helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;padding-left: 20px;font-size: 16px !important">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,.</p>
          </div>
          <div class='diamond2' id="diamond2">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <hr style="border: 1px solid #ff5a05;width: 1085px;">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `overflow: hidden;` to your parent div element. This will prevent any element inside your parent from overlapping (going out of your box). It is not possible though to make this affect any elements with `position` set to `absolute`. So try to build your diamond without using that property and it should just work fine.